# Datatables + web2py

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jquery-datatables, web2py

Tenho uma tabela que mostra resultados de uma busca no banco de dados e eu uso o plugin do Datatables para montar a paginação.

O problema é o seguinte: se passar de 500 registros o negocio fica lento (Praticamente todas as buscas que eu faço passa fácil de 500 registros).

Minha dúvida: existe uma maneira de fazer essa paginação ficar mais rápida? (Apenas lembrando que eu não posso fazer o preenchimento do datatables usando o ajax). Ou Existe algum plugin no mesmo esquema do Datatables que me de mais opções para a paginação?

Comment: Por que nao pode usar ajax?

Comment: Porque antes de mostrar a tabela com os registros eu mostro um formulario com alguns filtros de busca